# Editor role cannot see any posts

Tags: user-roles

I have a bunch of users who this morning have reported that they cannot see any posts on the website.
[image: View of posts for Editor role]

The users experiencing the issue are all editors so I created a new user with the role of 'Editor' and confirmed that the user cannot see any posts (see screenshot).

If an editor user's role is changed to 'Administrator' they can then see all the posts.

No changes have been made to the site recently and all these editor role users could see the posts at the end of last week.

Can anyone suggest a cause for this issue?

Comment: What software is this about? Please tag the question correctly or mention it in the question text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case was a plugin called "prevent direct access". I disabled it and everything worked again.
Maybe this helps.